# gRPC Client streaming is slow when TLS is enabled over high latency connections

Tags: ssl, grpc

We have been measuring the rate of gRPC client streaming in C# using grpc-dotnet compiled with DotNet-6. When TLS is not enabled, we see very high data rates of 380 Mbps (megabits per second when the client is in an Oakland datacenter and the server is in a Philadelphia datacenter (73ms pings times between client and server). However, when TLS is enabled, the rate drops to about 26 Mbps.

When the client and server are closer together (in the same datacenter with 1ms ping times), we see 860 Mbps with TLS disabled and 320 Mbps with TLS enabled. So, for low latency connections, the drop off is not as drastic, but the effect of TLS is still significant.

Each individual message sent by the client is about 50KB (well below the large block heap limit) and on the server side server side we set InitialConnectionWindowSize = InitialStreamWindowSize = 33,554,432 bytes (32 MB). A client streaming gRPC call is used to send 500 of the 50KB messages.

Version info:

- Google Protobuf: 3.21.4
- Grpc.AspNetCore: 2.47.0
- Grpc.Tools: 2.47.0
- Both client and server machines are Windows 10 Enterprise with 32 virtual processors and 64 GB memory and Hyper-V Network Adapters.

We are having a hard time understanding why TLS is causing such a sharp drop off in performance. Any ideas?

Comment: It is unclear whether you're using grpc-dotnet or the legacy Grpc.Core.  For grpc-dotnet, the version of dotnet runtime you're using is also important. E.g. see the dynamic window sizing algorithm added in .NET 6 : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-networking-improvements/#http-2-window-scaling. Also, sharing more details (OS, gRPC version, the character of the workload etc.) would be a prerequisite for finding out more.

Comment: Note that long time in the past, Grpc.Core used to ship unoptimized version of cipher implementations used in TLS so TLS was much slower that it needed to be, but that's something that's long been fixed (see FTR https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/ssl-performance.md)

Comment: Thank you, Jan. I added version information, including OS.  We are using grpc-dotnet and compiling against DotNet 6.  As far as workload, I added "A client streaming gRPC call is used to send 500 of the 50KB messages."  We are aware of the Http/2 window size fixes and also know that changing InitialConnectionWindowSize can significantly affect maximum rates, though the rate maxes out much lower when TLS is enabled. Is there other workload info that would be useful?